# Синхронные запросы Retrofit2 для Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

Можно ли использовать синхронные запросы Retrofit2 (`execute`), или нужно использовать только асинхронные (`enqueue`), применительно к Андроид? Не будут ли синхронные запросы нагружать главный поток приложения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать можно, но только не на UI потоке (Вы просто получите `NetworkOnMainThreadException`).

Синхронные запросы могут быть к месту, если Вам необходимо сделать несколько запросов подряд и Вы не хотите устраивать спагетти из колбэков, или когда Вы и так уже работаете в другом потоке, например, внутри `IntentService`.

Answer (score 3):

Синхронные запросы будут нагружать тот поток, в котором вы будете их выполнять.

Начиная c версии API 11 (Android 3.0 HONEYCOMB), сетевые запросы в главном потоке выбрасывают исключение `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Поэтому в нём вы их использовать не сможете в любом случае. Но никто не запрещает вам запускать их в любом другом background потоке.

Таким образом, ответом на ваш вопрос будет: в Android можно использовать  синхронные запросы Retrofit2 (`execute`), но только не из главного потока.